# The button is swaping how can I put a button where I want in my layout

Tags: android, button

I've a problem where I can't put a button where I want in my app layout... I searched for information about this but everyone says something different and I'm just confused... Can someone tell me what I have to do? See image below:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/uc" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="98dp"
        android:text="Button" />
```

[image]

Comment: try using a LinearLayout instead of Relative Layout? that might just do!

Comment: vertical or horizontal !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you can use the code below

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Button" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: O hepsi backgroundtur.. ben butonu siyah kısma yerleştirmek istedim. ama yine olmadı bu verdiğin kod ile.. kayma oluşuyor..emulatör mü neyden dolayı anlamış degilim.

Comment: Murşit, specific bir yere koyamazsın. Örneğin 100 X 300 de gözüksün diyemezsin. Bence backgroundaki gri yeri ayrı bir parça yap. Buttonu çevreleyen linearlayout backgrounduna bu parçayı vermeyi dene.

Comment: Bir bütün olarak aldığım için büyük ihtimalle o hata oluştu..Dediğiniz gibi tek düze bir resimden ziyade farklı parçalardan oluşan bir background oluşturacağım.....I'll try to make from the beginin' where background have to exists from multple images .. I think cos of the whole background emulator or whatever could not have to replace the buttons..Thank you again for your advicin' guys :)

Answer (score 1):

Steps you should follow:

Ask yourself "*Where do i want to put my button?*"; if the answer is **somewhere** below `button1` then it already is..

If you want to increase the distence then try a greater value for `android:layout_marginTop="98dp"`

If you want to have your `button2` at the bottom try `android:layout_marginBottom` instead of `android:layout_marginTop`

Comment: i wanna put it in the black blank where i draw with red elliptical. but when i try with linear or relative layout the button is swaping in emulator and in device too.that's why i uploaded the image that what my problem is !!

Comment: Sevgili kardeşim, ben siyah işaretlenmiş kısmın arkaplan resminin bir parçası olduğunu atlamışım. Kendin emülatör çıktısını alıp butonun gözükmesini istediğin aralığı işaretledin sanmışım. Sana önerim arka plan resmi kullanmak yerine o kısmı arka planı siyah olan bir container ile oluşturup butonu da üzerine koyman olur.

I didnt get that the black section on the screen was the part of bg image.I tho it was the part you marked to show the point you wanted your button to position.Instead of background image with black bar,you can use a black background container,position your button in it

Answer (score 1):

You Hardcoded the margin for your Button is "98dp" **android:layout_marginTop="98dp"**. And that Dark Black Rectangle is in Background of your image. So its not possible everytime to show the button/text/image exactly on the same part of background due to the different Screen sizes. Because your Background will stretch for large screens as you define it **fill_parent** but  you margin will remain same . You can use **ImageButton** and set its background to black. And remove that Dark Black rectangle from background.

Comment: the background images does not consist of two or more image.that is the hole background image.just one... i just wanna put it in that black line..

Comment: whole image is a background ! and i wanna put the button on the black line.. but when i put it on the button was swapped ..

Comment: Your background is stretched on bigger screen. But your button's position will be 96dp from the top. Remove that black part from your background. Make a new Imageview and put the black part in it and its Margintop="96dp" also, Then your image and Button will be on same position.

Comment: That will surely work for you. U can check your layout on different sizes screen in eclipse. By selecting the screen size for preview. If you select the big screen then see the thing that i am saying. Your Image will stretch but your button position will be remain same.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21687/discussion-between-rahul-kapoor-and-mursid)

Comment: Send me your background image on rahul1604kapoor@gmail.com, i will try on my computer